# Adding static pages to Drupal as is

Tags: theming

I want to add a static page to drupal.
To be specific, for example,

```
<html>
  <head>....</head>
  <body>
    Hi there
    <a href="/node/add/this">Link</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

No sidebars. No Drupal anything. Just a nice page some words.
I would like to have the base tag in the header
(e.g., `<base href="http://example.org/'>`) set for me.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to add a html file somewhere in your drupal folder. Apache or whatever web server you use will serve it as is.

Answer (score 1):

Why use Drupal? If you need to use Drupal (e.g. to restrict access based on roles), you can exclude this page from displaying whatever blocks you don't want to display in the visibility settings for that block. Just add your page to the excluded box.

Or you can write a module that uses hook_menu() and bypasses the entire Drupal theming system. The page example module in the example modules pack is a good starting point for how to do this.

Comment: I have some pages which are Drupalish and others which are not. I would like to have both.

Comment: Yes, I mean why use Drupal for the static pages. I covered your options regardless.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it via theming. Just copy your page.tpl.php to page-url_you_want.tpl.php and write whatever you want in that file.